# A beauty to behold

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> My first part is edible;
>   It can slide on the ground.
>   The other, mostly inedible;
>   Makes an annoying sound.

Who am I?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My guess is:

> BUTTERFLY

*My first part is edible*

> Butter can be eaten.

*It can slide on the ground*

> Butter is slippery.

*The other, mostly inedible*

> Only a few animals eat flies.

*Makes an annoying sound*

> The sound emitted by a fly is very annoying.

*Title*

> A Butterfly is surely a beauty to behold.